# cURL doesn't download actual PDF file; size is a few bytes

Tags: html, wget, curl

Using `curl`, I am attempting to download a PDF to my drive. However, the resulting file is only 210 bytes and cannot be opened!

```
curl -O 'https://www.wisdomtree.eu/en-ie/-/media/eu-media-files/key-documents/kids/etf-securities/kid---de000a1rx996---wisdomtree-physical-gold---eur-daily-hedged---en.pdf'
```

When I download the PDF with Google Chrome, the actual resulting file is 240 Kb and can be opened successfully.

It seems like `curl` is only getting some meta data – not the entire PDF:

```
<html>
<head>
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
<script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=5074a744e2e3d891814e9a2dace20bd4,719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3">
</script>
<body>
</body></html>%
```

I tried solving this with a few variants, including `curl -O -J -L` and some other things, and I also tried with `wget` – but I constantly seem to run into the same problem.

(I'm assuming that the server may be doing something with a blob URL, streaming, or redirect, I'm however unsure how to deal with this).

Comment: Are answers on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321710/why-wont-curl-download-this-link-when-a-browser-will) perhaps helpful?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Thank you, I have updated an answer to my question using information from that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at this [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/453579/136753) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, I could copy a functioning cURL from Google Chrome's *View > Developer > Developer Tools > Network* tab by reloading the URL with the Network tab open, and right-clicking the appearing `.pdf` in the file list and choosing *Copy > Copy as cURL*.

The copied cURL command includes several options, but I found that the server seems to require only the addition of the `-H 'cookie: <cookie data here>'` option.

```
curl -H 'cookie: <cookie data here>' -O 'https://www.wisdomtree.eu/en-ie/-/media/eu-media-files/key-documents/kids/etf-securities/kid---de000a1rx996---wisdomtree-physical-gold---eur-daily-hedged---en.pdf'
```

I am assuming this requires me to browse to the website first and actually obtain a session cookie.  I am not sure if retrieval can be accomplished without one.